# Limit user to access only 'docker inspect'?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sudo, docker

Is there a way to give access for a user (www-data to be exact) to access ONLY 'docker inspect'? Any working solution is acceptable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define this with sudoers(visudo command for editing):

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/docker inspect *
```

www-data user will have access to /usr/bin/docker binary with argument inspect and other arguments to this command. This command won't require password. If you don't want this behaviour remote "NOPASSWD:".

For example:

```
User can successfully run sudo docker inspect {{container_name}}
User can successfully run sudo docker inspect --help
User can't successfully run sudo docker run {{container}}
User can't successfully run sudo docker inspect without arguments
```

Comment: no, I need not to give access to docker binary, but ONLY to 'docker inspect' - e.g. with this argument

Comment: What do you mean by 'ONLY docker inspect'?

Have you tried my configuration for sudoers? It will provide access to docker inspect, but you can't run docker. I can elaborate in skype if you want.

Comment: oh, sorry, misread your comment. I'll try, thank you

Comment: I have edited my answer with examples. Is it what you want?

Comment: yes, that's I need, thank you) I'll test it out and write about the results

Comment: nope..

tester@CI-test: docker inspect production_web_1
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/images/production_web_1/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?[]

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Command should be "sudo docker inspect production_web_1"

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов have you tested it with sudo before command?

Comment: sorry for delay. Well, this seems to work.
Strange, that root: `sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/docker inspect productionmaster_web_1` fails with permission denied, but when nginx runs it by itself using `sudo /usr/bin/docker inspect productionmaster_web_1` — it works. Why  `sudo -u` fails?

Comment: No problem:) Because sudo -u works from another user. Try to do sudo -u www-data sudo /usr/bin/docker inspect blablabal

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't have any granularity of access permission, but you could write an alternative client quite easily that uses the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) to implement just the part you need.

That client could then be setuid to a user with permissions to the Docker socket.